# Spring boot and Zuul proxy DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction Error

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul, gateway

I have a simple app that uses Netflix Zuul as an API gateway

I added the Zuul dependency in the pom.xml file as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and `@EnableZuulProxy` for the main class of the app

The problem is that whenever I try to run the API, It fails to start and shows in the console:

> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction'
> in your configuration.

I couldn't solve the issue, what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was solved when I added the following dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and as a result, spring also asked me to add this to my app configuration:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

Then my API ran successfully without failing or throwing any exception